# How to save words with a child voice

Tags: android

I need to find a way to save speech with a child voice to add it to my android project,
I've found a lot of TTS (Text to Speech) but nothing with a child voice.
Is there a way that I can record words with a child voice or maybe a TTS that support this,Please Help

Comment: Since you want to add audio files as resources to an Android project (and not do it programmatically), this isn't actually a question about programming. I'd look at TTS followed by pitch change on audacity (assuming you want the chipmunk effect). Otherwise you'll need more advanced effects, but again, not using code.